# Blade Template Engine - Jenssegers blade

Tags: template-engine, laravel-blade

ı want to use blade template engine without laravel. I install this https://github.com/jenssegers/blade but don' t use this.

> My index.php :

```
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';
 use jenssegers\blade;

 $blade = new Blade('views', 'cache');

 echo $blade->make('homepage', ['name' => 'John Doe']);
 ?>
```

ı have a error :

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'jenssegers\blade' not found in /var/www/html/index.php:8
>   Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 8

Comment: the namespace is `Jenssegers\Blade\Blade;`

Comment: I do and have this error :  `php index.php
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(cache/1a18700cc938ca58cfc2353ade01e041f7230feb.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/vendor/illuminate/filesystem/Filesystem.php on line 122
PHP Warning:  include(cache/1a18700cc938ca58cfc2353ade01e041f7230feb.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/vendor/illuminate/view/Engines/PhpEngine.php on line 43
...
`

Comment: seems to be a file permission error ,do you have a cache folder?

Comment: no, I edit this: `$blade = new Blade('views');` and have error `php index.php
PHP Warning:  Missing argument 2 for Jenssegers\Blade\Blade::__construct(), called in /var/www/html/index.php on line 5 and defined in /var/www/html/vendor/jenssegers/blade/src/Blade.php on line 34
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: cachePath in /var/www/html/vendor/jenssegers/blade/src/Blade.php on line 37
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Please provide a valid cache path. in /var/www/html/vendor/illuminate/view/Compilers/Compiler.php:36
Stack trace:
`

Comment: add a folder named cache, create the blade using 2 arguments, as in your code

Comment: blade compiles the blade syntax into normal code in the cache folder

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much, now ı don' t have a error. But ı have 1 question. Can I turn off cache? I don't want to caching.

Comment: yes, you can, remove blade :))) seriously:)))

Comment: I understand :D Again, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

For the record, this error is caused by the folder where the library was installed. They updated the composer.json for this reason.  As a sidenote: psr-0 and psr-4 are broken, and it's one of the cause.  I had the same problem with a couple of libraries.

Anyways.  You can try this one: (one class, no dependency, 100% performance friendly, and it's updated).

https://github.com/EFTEC/BladeOne/

(Disclaimer: I am the author and it's free for the community)